# MATLAB- Waterfilling algorithm- infinity loop

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop, infinity

I'm trying to write a matlab code to carry out Waterfilling algorithm in MIMO channels. I've written the code below but there is something wrong with my WHLIE loop, it never ends and I cannot figure out why?!! I'm trying to write the code for the given formula below. Could you please help me to fix it?
[image]

here is the code:

```
% Power allocated using Waterfilling 
C_eigen=zeros(1,numel(SNR));
C_equal_t2=zeros(1,r);
K=zeros(1,numel(L));

P=zeros(1,r);
sq=0;
for i=1:numel(SNR)

    p=1;
    go = true;
     while go

        for j=1:r-p+1
         K(j)=1/L(j);
         T =sum(K);
        end;
         m =(1/(r-p+1))*(1+ (1/SNR(i))*T);
             for j=1:r-p+1 
             P(j)= m-(1/(SNR(i)*L(j)));
                     if P(r-p+1)< 0
                         P(r-p+1)=0;
                         p =p+1;
                     end;
             end;
        sq = sum(P);
        if sq <= 1.00005
            go = false;
        end;
     end;
      for j=1:r
        C_equal_t2(j)=log2(1+SNR(i)*L(j)*P(j));
        C_eigen(i)=sum(C_equal_t2);
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Try storing `sq` into an array, and plot the results. If your algorithm does what it is supposed to do, `sq` should go (asymptotically) down. If it doesn't, you know the mistake is elsewhere. If it does go down, but never below `1.00005`, you've chosen your threshold too stringent. As a side note, I always include a `whilse go && iter < max_iter`  clause, to make certain that the loop is killed regardless of convergence after a given maximum number of iterations.

Comment: remove the semi-colon here [P(j)= m-(1/(SNR(i)*L(j)));] and keep an eye on the values, see if its what you're expecting?

Comment: I think I've found the problem but don't know how to fix it. The Problem is that when for example P(3)=0 and P(1)and P(2) have + values the iteration must continue till the total P(1)+P(2) becomes below < 1.0005